# Why does `getline` on `wifstream` read garbled input from UTF-16 encoded file?

Tags: c++, linux, utf-16, wifstream

While trying to read a UTF-16 encoded file with hints from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153212/11390852), I got the problem that, after reading few thousand characters, the `getline`-method starts to read in garbage mojibake.

Here is my main:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

int main(void) {

    std::wifstream wif("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    if (wif.is_open())
    {
        wif.imbue(
            std::locale(
                wif.getloc(),
                new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>
            )
        );

        std::wstring wline;
        while (std::getline(wif, wline))
        {
            std::wcout << wline;
        }

        wif.close();
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

The `test.txt` file contains `FF`, `FE` byte order mark, followed by 100 lines with 80 `'a'`s in each line. Here is a bash-script that generates `test.txt` on *nix:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n -e \\xFF\\xFE > test.txt
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
  for i in $(seq 1 80)
  do
    echo -n -e \\x61\\x00 >> test.txt
  done
  echo -n -e \\x0A\\x00 >> test.txt
done
```

Here is how I compile and run the main:

```
g++-8 -std=c++17 -g main.cpp -o m && ./m
```

**What I expected:** 8000 `'a'`s are printed.

**What actually happened:**

After printing few thousand `a`s, the output changes to following garbage:

> aaaaaaaaaa愀愀愀愀愀愀愀愀愀愀

and occasionally non-printable characters that look like `0A00` in a rectangle.

The `愀`-character has binary codepoint value of `110000100000000`, so it looks like `a`-byte followed by `0`-byte.

It seems as if some bytes are lost during reading, and from then on, everything is misaligned, and all the remaining symbols are decoded incorrectly. Or, because the output ends with a `0A00`-thingie, it might be that the endianness is reversed after reading few thousand `a`s, but this behavior also wouldn't make any sense whatsoever.

Why does this happen, and what's the easiest way to fix it?

Comment: Note that [`std::codecvt_utf16`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16) have been deprecated in the C++17 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. What would be the current alternative? [Use the deprecated stuff or write it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072112/11390852)? If this is the case, I'd prefer to get some deprecation warnings rather than rewriting it myself.

Comment: Probably [`std::codecvt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple workaround (but not a general solution)**

If you are sure that the input file will have a particular endianness, then you can simply hardcode the endianness [as shown in the example in the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16):

```
        wif.imbue(
            std::locale(
                wif.getloc(),
                new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>
            )
        );
```

With a hardcoded `std::little_endian`, the problem seems to disappear, and the file is read correctly. It probably won't work for files with the opposite endianness.